# Integration with an external Kafka using Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We want to integrate our system with an external Kafka using Kafka Connect.
And we already have a tested connector.

Since Kafka is external, we have the following  expectations/limitations:

1. We cannot install, configure or update the Kafka
2. We cannot install, configure or update the Kafka Connect ( For example, if we want to use the
   internal one that comes with the kafka)
3. We do not manage topic/user ACL for Kafka Connect etc

[image]

Some Questions:

1. What permissions (ACL, auto-generated topics etc) does an external Kafka Connect need when integrating with Kafka?
2. Is it good practice to use an external Kafka Connect?  I tried to find information in Google and I can't.
3. Maybe in my case it is not recommended to use the Kafka Connect?

Comment: Maybe it could be better to use MirrorMaker 2.0 to replicate data from external cluster to your own (which you can manage) and then use Kafka Connect to integrate with your system

Answer (score 1):

Each Kafka Connect cluster requires a status, config, and offsets topic. Ideally, create these manually to ensure replication and partitioning is adequate.

Then, obviously, access to the topics you're sinking/sourcing.

> Is it good practice to use an external Kafka Connect

Yes. Best practices say not to run the process on the broker, and treat Kafka Connect like any other client.

> Maybe in my case it is not recommended to use the Kafka Connect

Ultimately, depends on your use case. For example, Apache Nifi, Streamsets, among other tools allow more flexibility in connections